# Bash - if condition command not found

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to execute a quite simple test by using :

```
YY=${array[17]}
echo $YY

if [ "$YY" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "do.."
else
    echo "here"
fi
```

But this code returns :

```
0
./script.sh: line 303: $'[\302\2400': command not found
```

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Dunno what that error is but if YY isn't an integer then using single `[` will fail. In almost all cases it is better the use double `[[` i.e `if [[ "$YY" -ne 0 ]]`

Comment: Thank for your reply but the problem stay the same, it returns line 302: $'[[\302\2400': command not found

Comment: Could you give an example of YY value - since you are calling an array index that we cannot see.

Comment: What editor do you use to edit your scripts?

Comment: I am using Geany in order to write scripts

Comment: `$'\302\240'` is the character U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE. Replace the unbreakable space by an ordinary space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$'[\302\2400'` is bash's way of writing a three-character string: a "[" followed by a non-breaking space (unicode U+00A0; in HEX UTF-8 that's c2 a0, but the shell prints it in octal as 302 240), and finally the digit "0". Based on this, I'm pretty sure you have a non-breaking space between `[` and `"$YY"`, and you just need to replace that with a normal space.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have some weird chars in your number string...Maybe try using REG_EX to extract numbers from a string..

```
YY=${array[17]}
echo "\"$YY\""

#Use reg ex to extract number and leave behind garbage
REG_EX="([0-9]+)" 

if [[ $YY =~ $REG_EX ]]
then
  YY=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  if [ "$YY" -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "do.."
  else
    echo "here"
  fi
else
  echo "Trouble extracting number from YY"
fi
```